# How do I recover deleted files?

Tags: centos, data-recovery, system-recovery

Today I mistakenly deleted files inside the public_html folder.
There is no backup of deleted files.
Is there a way to recover information?
thanks

Comment: Depends how valuable the data is, and how much you want to pay. First step is **stop writing to the file-system (stop using the computer). Every write may write over your data. The last step, is to start using a revision control system.

Comment: If the relevant filesystem is `ext3` or `ext4`, you can use `debug2fs` to attempt to recover the deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

I'd shut the system down, use a Windows PC with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) to create a LiveUSB from [Xubuntu 19.10](https://xubuntu.org/download) with persistence, install [Photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) on the LiveUSB, then use Photorec to recover your deleted files.